# Scalding: Need to read in different files format based on an argument

Tags: scala, scalding

I'm trying to create on script that will create  pipe from a file in either avro format or delimted based on a value passed as an argument in the command line.  I want to then take that pipe and do some operations on it.  What I have so far is this:

```
val fileType = args("file_type").toString
def makeFile (types:String):RichPipe {
  if (types == "avro") {UnpackedAvroSource(args("input")).addTrap(Tsv("errorFile.txt"))}
  else if (types == "delim") {Csv(args("input"), separator = "\t", fields = schema).addTrap(Tsv(errors)) }

val fileSource = makeFile(fileType)

fileSource
  .project('field1, 'field2, ....)
```

This produces an error that says:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: com.twitter.scalding.RichPipe
else if (types == "delim") {
     ^
one error found
```

It seems like its throwing an error on the else if statement which does't really make sense, but I can't figure out what it's trying to read when it finds a "unit" type and is expecting the RichPipe.

Alternatively, if there is a better way to go about this, please free to suggest.

Comment: In line `def makeFile (types:String):RichPipe {` you have forgotten to add the `=`, it should be: `def makeFile (types:String):RichPipe = {`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version:

```
def makeFile (types:String):RichPipe = {
  if (types == "avro") {UnpackedAvroSource(args("input")).addTrap(Tsv("errorFile.txt"))}
  else if (types == "delim") {Csv(args("input"), separator = "\t", fields = schema).addTrap(Tsv(errors))}
  else {sys.error(s"Wrong type: $types") }
```

The problem was: You missed an `=` sign in the definition and used `if` without `else` (which results in `Unit`).

Alternatively you could use pattern matching too, something like:

```
def makeFile (types:String):RichPipe = {
  types matches {
    case "avro" => {
      UnpackedAvroSource(args("input")).addTrap(Tsv("errorFile.txt"))
    }
    case "delim" => {
      Csv(args("input"), separator = "\t", fields = schema).addTrap(Tsv(errors))
    }
    case _=> sys.error(s"Wrong type: $types") //Optional if you are ok with MatchError
  }
}
```